# Magento transaction emails responsive

Tags: magento, email

Does anyone know if it is possible to make the Magento Transactional emails (such as Order Confirmation) responsive, so that they also look good on Mobile devices?
Thank you in advance.
BJ

p.s. I searched the Internet for a long time, but could not find any information about it.

Comment: How do you know, your customer has a mobile device to view to mail on?

Comment: Well all users these days watch their email also on their mobile no?

Comment: Maybe, but what I meant was that your Magento doesn't know if he has to send out a normal or a mobile mail unless you tell it yo do so. But, I think there is no function for that (yet).

Comment: ah ok thx. My idea was just to send our a responsive email template, just as you do with a website. And the client will detect how to present the email.

When you make newsletters for example with Mailchimp, there are many responsive templates. I was just wondering if that could also be used in the transactional Emails in Magento.

But thanks for your input.

Comment: You may want to check out the work I did here: https://magemail.co/magehackday-2014/ - it's not fully baked for all Magento transactional emails but pretty close.

Answer (score 0):

Just login in Admin and move on `System->Transactional Emails` and click on `Create New Template` now load the template from the drop down e.g. `New Order`.

Them write the responsive CSS in the template and save with different name.

Now move on `System->Configuration->Sales Emails` and select your custom template for `New Order Confirmation Template`, and save it.

Comment: Don't forget to accept the answer if its solve your problem to help someone else. Thanks